# MSSQL Right / Left Trim by Character

Tags: sql-server

How can I trim last (or first) characters from a string in SQL server? 
Given a string like `'~~abc~~'`, the output will be `'~~abc'`.

For example, in Postgresql, `SELECT trim(trailing '~' FROM '~~abc~~')` returns `'~~abc'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There should be more efficient methods if you are doing this for a lot of data, but one way to do this could be by using `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()` and `PATINDEX()`**

```
DECLARE @string varchar(255) = '~~abc~~';

SELECT RIGHT(@string,LEN(@String)-PATINDEX('%[^~]%',@string)+1); -- Remove leading ~
SELECT LEFT(@string,LEN(@String)-PATINDEX('%[^~]%',REVERSE(@string))+1);-- Remove trailing ~
```

**Results**

```
(No column name)
abc~~

(No column name)
~~abc
```